# Express JS render view with received image

Tags: javascript, html, api, express, httprequest

I am working with two `Express JS` applications one is an `API` and second is application that is using this `API` by making requests and displaying received informations to user.

In `API` route I'm sending image as response:

```
router.get('/:customer_id',authController.isAuthenticated,(req,res) => {
    .
    . Retrieving customer data
    .

    return res.sendFile('/uploads/'+foundCustomer.doc_path);
});
```

And later another application is getting this `document`:

```
router.get('/:customer_id',(req,res) => {
    var options = {
    url: 'http://'+config.API.user+':'+config.API.password+'@'+config.API.host+':'+config.API.port+'/customers/'+req.params.customer_id
    };

    request(options,(err,response,body)=>{
        return res.render('customer/show',{
            document: ?, // Send document as parameter to view
        });
    });
});
```

In this point I want to render `customer/show`(EJS view engine) with customer `document`, but I don't want to save this document in my application files, because `document` is only needed to display in view (customer details and document are stored in another application).

I was trying to create `temporary` directory in my application structure, but it is difficult to manage deleting those not needed documents (Application has many `users` and at the same time many `customers` can be displayed).

Another solution that I was trying to implement is to make `Ajax` request on client side and latter append received document to `<object data='document'>`. But this request has to be authenticated with `user` and `password`, so I realised that storing credentials on client side javascript is not the best idea...

I am not sure that is it even possible to `render` and display image without saving in application files?

I would be grateful for any help, maybe the best workaround is to somehow manage `temporarily` saved documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution (tested), using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) to make `API` request:

In my route I'm going to make HTTP request to my `API` to retrieve `PDF` file(document):

```
axios.get(`http://my-api/customer/id`).then(response => {
   var photo =  new Buffer(response.data, 'binary').toString('base64');

   return res.render('customers/show',{
       document: document
   });
});
```

In my `ejs` view, I'm using HTML `object` tag to display received PDF:

```
<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,<%-document%>"></object>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a File object inside EJS template then use that for `src` attribute on an `<img>` ? You're already getting the raw buffer/blob from your image API server. Store it inside template.

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob

```
// place this code (store this variable) inside of your EJS template
// so it can be used by the client-side JS
var aBlob = new Blob( array[, options]); // Where array is the raw buffer data returned from your image API server
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

```
var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL( aBlob ); // Where object is a Blob object
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject

```
const img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = objectURL;
```

Comment: I have some syntax error. I'm trying to construct `aBlob` object inside EJS file like this: `<script>
    var aBlob = new Blob("<%-customer_document%>");
</script>` where `customer_document` is String received from API. I am getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" error there

Comment: Remove the surrounding quotes.

Comment: Convert the string to buffer new Buffer(<string>)

Comment: `var buffer = new Buffer(<%-student_document%>);` this syntax or with quotes is giving error as well. Do you have any tested code example from previous projects?

Comment: Your `<%- student_document %>` .. is it an image file ?

Comment: [Screenshot](https://pasteboard.co/Hm4cBRE.jpg) this document is body of my response. You can check attached screenshot.